# HTML input type=date weekdays

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any ways to make html input date only allow to pick weekdays calendar?
I wish to prevent past dates as well. Can i do this without using jquery datepicker? Or can it be done using css? Something like hide weekends from calendar.

```
input type="date" name="date" id="date"
```

Comment: *"Can i do this without using jquery datepicker?"* - Of course. jQuery and its datepicker are "just" a collection of JS functions that somebody else wrote for you, so you don't *need* them...

Comment: can you provide the solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent past dates by setting `min` attribute.

And I think you cannot disable the weekends with javascript.

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
```

```html
<input type="date" name="date" id="date">
```

Answer (score 1):

Not natively but you could do this with a small javascript by disabling the form and showing a visual cue if a weekend is selected, heres a quick snippet to get an idea

```
var warning = $('<p>').text('Error you cannot select a weekend')
$('#myinput').change(function(e) {

      var d = new Date(e.target.value)
      if(d.getDay() === 6 || d.getDay() === 5) {
        $('#mysubmit').attr('disabled',true)
        $('#myinput').after(warning);
      } else {
        warning.remove()
       $('#mysubmit').attr('disabled',false);
    }
})
```